# Заменить знак ' ' пустотой в массиве char

Tags: c++

Есть массив char например char n1[] = "a  bc def  ghijk"; нужно все вторые пробелы заменить пустотой , побывал примерно так

```
void clean(char* n){
bool f=false;
for(int i=0;n[i]!=NULL;i++){

    if(f==false && n[i]==' ' && n[i+1]==' '){
        f=true;

    }else if(n[i]==' ' && f==true){
        n[i]=(char)00;
        f=false;
    } 

}
cout<<n;
}

int main() {
char n1[] = "a  bc def  ghijk";
clean(n1);
}
```

но тогда на выходе выходит пустая строка , вернее 1 символ и там где по идеи должен убраться символ пустая строка.

Comment: Фраза "все вторые пробелы" не совсем понятно. Вам нужно удалить повторяющиеся пробелы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вам нужно удалить все рядом стоящие пробелы в строке за исключением первого.

В этом случае вы можете воспользовать стандартным алгоритмом `std::unique`, объявленном в заголовке `std::algorithm` . Например

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    char s[] = "a    bc   def ghijk   "; 

    std::cout << "\"" << s << "\"\n";

    std::unique( s, s + sizeof( s ), []( char c1, char c2 ) { return ( c1 == c2 ) && ( c1 == ' ' ); } );

    std::cout << "\"" << s << "\"\n";
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
"a    bc   def ghijk   "
"a bc def ghijk "
```

Вместо выражения в вызове алгоритма

```
s + sizeof( s )
```

вы можете использовать выражение

```
s + std::strlen( s ) + 1
```

Если вам самому надо написать такую функцию, то такая функция может выглядеть, например, следующим образом:

```
#include <iostream>

char * remove_blanks( char *s )
{
    if ( *s )
    {        
        char *p = s; 
        char *q = p + 1;

        do
        {
            if ( *p != ' ' || *q != ' ' )
            {                
                ++p;
                if ( p != q + 1 ) *p = *q;
            }               
            ++q;
        } while ( *p );
    }

    return s;
}

int main()
{
    char s[] = "a    bc   def ghijk   "; 

    std::cout << "\"" << s << "\"\n";

    std::cout << "\"" << remove_blanks( s ) << "\"\n";
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
"a    bc   def ghijk   "
"a bc def ghijk "
```

Если вам надо написать функцию, которая к тому же будет удалять ведущие и конечные пробелы, то такая функция может выглядеть следующим образом

```
char * remove_blanks( char *s )
{
    char *p = s;
    char *q = s;

    while ( *q == ' ' ) ++q;

    while ( *p )
    {
        if ( *q == '\0' && *( p - 1 ) == ' ' )
        {            
            *( p - 1 ) = *q;
        }
        else
        {            
            if ( *q != ' ' || *( q - 1 ) != ' ' )
            {
                if ( p != q ) *p = *q;
                if ( *p ) ++p;
            }
            ++q;
        }            
    }            

    return s;
}
```

Comment: все бы хорошо , но нельзя использовать #include <cstring>

Comment: @user2420249 Смотрите мой обновленный ответ.

Comment: а как ешё первый и последний символ что-бы не был пробелом учесть

Comment: @user2420249 Напишите отдельную функцию типа trim или измените ту функцию, которую я вам показал. Для этого достаточно просто в функции найти первый не пробельный символ..

Comment: с первым понял , с последним не понял

Comment: @user2420249 Я дополнил свой ответ.

Comment: спасибо , работает , пойду разбирать код